# I am trying to update Visual Studio on a MAC to the latest version but I got error message below any help it will be much appreciate

Tags: macos, visual-studio

Cannot update while running on a read-only volume. The application is on a read-only volume. Please move the application and try again. If you're on macOS Sierra or later, you'll need to move the application out of the Downloads directory. See this link for more information

Answer (score 0):

Try quitting the application and dragging it from your downloads folder to your applications folder. If not there is also a link to a few terminal commands to try here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7426#issuecomment-425093469